# Почему объект уничтожается при переходе на другую страницу

Tags: php, ооп

Доброй ночи. Продолжаю изучать PHP (3 курс Специалиста, там где новостной сайт). Столкнулся с такой вот засадой.

Есть основной файл

```
            <?php
            require_once ("NewsDB.class.php");
            $news = new NewsDB();
            $errMsg="";
            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
            require_once ("save_news.inc.php");}
            require_once ("delete_news.inc.php");
            ?>
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                    <title>Новостная лента</title>
                    <meta charset="utf-8" />
            </head>
            <body>
              <h1>Последние новости</h1>
              <?php
            If ($errMsg) echo "<h3>$errMsg</h3>";
            ?>
              <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
                Заголовок новости:<br />
                <input type="text" name="title" /><br />
                Выберите категорию:<br />
                <select name="category">
                  <option value="1">Политика</option>
                  <option value="2">Культура</option>
                  <option value="3">Спорт</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                Текст новости:<br />
                <textarea name="description" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea><br />
                Источник:<br />
                <input type="text" name="source" /><br />
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Добавить!" />
            </form>
            <?php
            require_once 'get_news.inc.php';
            ?>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Туда require save_news.inc.php

```
            <?php
            $title = $news->clearStr($_POST[title]);
            $category = $news->clearInt($_POST[category]);
            $description = $news->clearStr($_POST[description]);
            $source = $news->clearStr($_POST[source]);
            If (empty($title) or empty($description)){
                $errMsg = "Заполните все поля формы";
            }else{If ($news->saveNews($title, $category, $description, $source)){
                    header('Location:news.php');exit;}
                    else {
                        $errMsg = "Ошибка при добавлении новости";
            }}
```

и delete_news.inc.php

```
        <?php
        var_dump($news);
        //require_once 'NewsDB.class.php';
        //$news = new NewsDB();
        $iddel = $news->clearInt($_GET[iddel]);
        if ($iddel>0){
        {if($news->deleteNews($iddel)){
            $errMsg="Запись удалена";
            header("Location:news.php");
        }else 
            $errMsg="Ошибка при удалении";
            header("Location:news.php");
        }}
```

Так вот save_news нормально работает и сохраняет новости.
А вот delete_news не хочет работать, пишет `Fatal error: Call to a member function clearInt() on a non-object` 
При require на основной странице var_dump во второй строке файлв delete_news показывает, что это объект. А когда переходим по ссылке из файла getnews то объект уничтожается. Если раскомментить 3 и 4 строки в delete и создать объект $news  заново, то работает нормально. Подскажите в чем засада? Почему объект уничтожается.

На всякий случай вот get_news

```
    <?php
    $posts= $news->getNews();
    $i=1;
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        echo "Новость $i";
        $i++;
        $datetim =  date("d-m-Y", $post['datetime']);
    ?>
    <h3><?= $post[title]?></h3>
    <p><?= $post[description]?></p>
    <p><?= $post[source]?></p>
    <p><?= $datetim ?></p>
    <a href="delete_news.inc.php?iddel=<?=$post['id']?>">Удалить новость сверху</a></br>
    <?php
    };
```

Comment: вот ссылка на все файлы https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19358018/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%8B/%21temp/news/news.zip

Comment: `<a href="delete_news.inc.php?iddel=<?=$post['id']?>">Удалить новость сверху</a></br>` а что Вы еще хотели? Открывается напрямую `delete_news.inc.php` https://habrahabr.ru/post/179399/

Comment: Сначала закоментили $news, а теперь жалуемся, что на ём нельзя вызывать методы, потому что он не является объектом?

Comment: Закоментил я, потому что мне кажется что оно должно работать и так.

Comment: ReinRaus - да открывается, но ведь и при добавлении товара тоже переходит на новую страницу, только там открывается страница через POST `<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">` что в этом разница?

Comment: а, кажись понял.  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] - мы остаемся на главной странице.  Скрипт просто встроен by "require_once"

Comment: А при явном переходе на другую страницу объекты уничтожаются. Так? Пока не сильно понял условий когда объект уничтожается.

Comment: Удалите у всех файлов Inc.php часть php, оставьте только inc. То, что создано для инклуда— должно инклудиться, а не вызываться напрямую. Подумайте над архитектурой Вашего приложения. Подскажу, что самая простая и эффективная практика- один файл php на всё приложение, но он инклудит те модули, которые нужны в конкретном запросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неверно понимаете механизм работы вашей странички, отсюда, как мне кажется и проблемы.

Пройду по пунктам:

1. Каждая загрузка страницы в браузере, каждое обновление страницы заного загружает ваш скрипт. То есть php заного обрабатывает ваш код каждый раз. (о кеширование пока можно не вспонимать).
2. Первым загружается именно тот файл, который указан в адресной строке браузера. Это может быть main.php, news.php, index.php или любой другой, но именно он будет загружен первым.
3. Далее по мере выполнения основного скрипта, подключаются другие скрипты, если указаны инструкции для их подключания - include или require

Давайте взглянем на ваш файл delete_news.inc.php:

Вы проверяете переменную $news и в ней будет объект, но только в том случае, если где-то раньше это переменная была установлена. Именно поэтому при загрузке основного файла в переменной будет лежать ссылка на объект.
Но если вы загрузите файл delete_news.inc.php напрямую, переменная будет пуста и вы получите ошибку. Поэтому если вы хотите использовать этот файл отдельно, вам нужно раскомментировать подключение NewsBD и установку переменной $news.

Давайте вернемся к вашему основному файлу, к коду:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    require_once ("save_news.inc.php");}
    require_once ("delete_news.inc.php");
?>
```

У вас нехватает закрывающей } после подключения delete_news.inc.php. А само подключение этого файла только при пост запросе выглядит бессмысленным, потому что удаление новости происходит по GET параметру и от POST никак не зависит.

Вообще в приведенном вами коде четко видна огромная проблема проистекающая из подобного подхода разработки сайтов. Подключая нужные файлы вручную, вы рано или поздно придете к тому, что для каких-либо изменений вам придется перелапатить уйму файлов, и это будет адова работа.

Comment: Я уже понял про перегрузку скриптов с каждой страницей. И большое Вам спасибо, что разъяснили это.

Comment: Я закомментировал, так как пытался добиться чтоб работало без этого. В общем эксперементировал. Раньше там вообще не было подключения класса. Теперь понятно.

Comment: Там закрывающая } после подключения первого файла, второй подключается без условия, да и насколько я вижу он и не нужен вообще в главном.  По поводу подключения файлов я так понимаю лучше пользоваться автоматической загрузкой. Попробую ее тут реализовать. Это все чисто учебный проектик.

Comment: Вариант приближенный к идеалу - единая точка входа + автозагрузка

Comment: Имхо, искренне рекомендую взять какой-нибудь микрофремворк или из тех что попроще и сделать какой-нибудь сайт на нем. Самописка - это конечно познавательно, но это хождение по мукам и граблям.

Comment: @SimpsSams Если бы получили ответ на ваш вопрос, и считаете его правильным, то нучно принять ответ как правильный.

Comment: @Victor  спасибо - ваши советы действительно полезные.

Comment: Я так и планирую, после прохождения курсов по PHP попробовать CodeIgniter потом Yii. CakePHP уже щупал.